# Dynamic cursor PERVASIVE

Tags: cursor, pervasive

I'm trying to create SP with dynamic cursor for obtain the result of any Select statement

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CursorTest (:query IN VARCHAR(5000)) ;
BEGIN
DECLARE :out VARCHAR;
DECLARE :dynamicCursor CURSOR FOR  EXEC (:query);
OPEN dynamicCursor;
/* cursor loop */ 
    Cursorloop:
    LOOP
    FETCH NEXT FROM `enter code here`Cursorloop INTO :out;
    End LOOP; 
    CLOSE dynamicCursor;
    END;
```

I have 2 problems on that, Declare the cursor with the dynamic query and output the result as a row.

```
Thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question is tagged `pervasive` I'm assuming you want to achieve this in PervasiveSQL.

I don't think what you are trying to do is possible there. The main reason for this is that - to my knowledge - P-SQL has no aggregate functions to combine arbitrary columns or rows into a string (like e.g. PostgreSQL's `string_agg`).

Secondly, P-SQL does not support querying by column number. The `:query` argument can be any statement (even an invalid one!), so you don't know how many columns it'll produce.

On a more essential note: what is it exactly that you want to achieve? This stored procedure looks to me like an overly complicated way of just executing `:query`, and having no means of handling the result. If logging or analysis is your goal, wouldn't you be better off by using an external, more flexible (scripting) language to deal with the result set? Admittedly SQL *is* a programming language, but it has its limitations.